# how to remove current mediasource in exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I use exoplayer2 for playing music. For setting mediasource, I use prepare method. But I want to remove current mediasource and set the current source to null. Is there any way to set the current mediasource to null not creating a new player?

Answer (score 0):

there is a method that can fit your question:

```
player.removeMediaItem(0);
```

Source: https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/testutil/Action.RemoveMediaItems.html

Answer (score 0):

Like Marc said, you can remove the current MediaItem using:

```
player.removeMediaItem(0)
```

I would also like to mention that you don't need to stop the player first.

If you simply want to play a new MediaItem or MediaSource, use

```
player.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
```

or

```
player.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
```

If you're using `removeMediaItems` The docs are a bit unclear on the usage of removeMediaItems.

```
player.removeMediaItems(start, end)
```

Where end is non inclusive.